# Cross Site Scripting: Is restricting the use of < and > tags an effective way to reduce Cross Site Scripting?

Tags: javascript, xss

If I want to prevent XSS, would restricting the input of special characters such as < and > in all text entry forms be the best way to prevent it?

I mean, this would prevent the entry of html tags such as `<script>` , `<img>` etc. and effectively block XSS.

Would you agree?

Comment: no, all depends on where the data is being inserted into the page.

Comment: @epascarello, Would you care to elaborate please?

Comment: if content is being inserted as an attribute removing <> does nothing.

Comment: It would effectively stop people talking about a lot of algebra. In general: Escape data, don't discard it.

Comment: if the output context is between tags (.innerHTML), then yes.

Answer (score 3):

No.  The **best** way to prevent it is to ensure that all the information you output onto the page is appropriately encoded.

---

Some possible examples of why angle brackets (and other special character blocking) is insufficient:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/36629/cross-site-scripting-without-special-chars

Comment: both the relevant answers in the link are long outmoded for the vast majority of users

Answer (score 2):

One of the biggest problems with preventing XSS is that a single webpage has many different encoding contexts, some of which may or may not overlap. There's a reason double-encoding is considered inherently dangerous.

Let's see an example. You prohibit `<` and `>`, so I can no longer input a HTML element in your page, right? Well, not quite. For example, if you put the text I loaded into an attribute, it will be interpreted differently:

```
onload="document.write('&lt;script&gt;window.alert(&quot;Gotcha!&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;')"
```

There's plenty of such opportunities, and each needs their own variant of correct encoding. Even encoding the input as proper HTML text (e.g. turning `<` into `&lt;`) may be a vulnerability if the text is then taken in javascript, and used in something like `innerHTML`, for example.

The same kind of issue occurs with any kind of URL (`img src="javascript:alert('I can't let you do that, Dave')"`), or with embedding user input in any kind of script (`\x3C`). URL is especially dangerous, since it does *triple* encoding - URL encoding, (X)HTML encoding and possibly JavaScript encoding. I'm not sure if it's even possible to have user input that is safe under those conditions :D

Ideally, you want to limit your area of exposure as much as you can. Do not read from the generated document unless you trust the user (e.g. an admin). Avoid multiple encoding, and always make sure you know exactly where each potentially unsafe encoding goes. In XHTML, you have a great option in `CDATA` sections, which make encoding potentially dangerous code easy, but that might be interpreted incorrectly by browsers that don't support XHTML correctly. Otherwise, use a proper documented encoding method - in JS, this would be `innerText`. Of course, you need to make sure that your JS script isn't compromised due to user data.